# check if facebook URL redirected or not?

Tags: facebook, url, redirect

i want to check if the url's in my database are reaching the facebook page they should or redirected to "www.facebook.com".

this is the code i use:

```
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass');
mysql_select_db('database');
?>

<?php
$query = "SELECT data_txt FROM jos_sobi2_fields_data WHERE fieldid=8 ";

$result = mysql_query($query);

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$url = $row['data_txt'];

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

foreach($row as $url) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $out = curl_exec($ch);

$out = str_replace("\r", "", $out);

$headers_end = strpos($out, "\n\n");
if( $headers_end !== false ) { 
    $out = substr($out, 0, $headers_end);
}   

$headers = explode("\n", $out);
foreach($headers as $header) {
    if( substr($header, 0, 10) == "Location: " ) { 
        $target = substr($header, 10);

        echo "[$url] redirects to [$target]<br>";
        continue 2;
    }   
}   

echo "[$url] does not redirect<br>";
}
?>
```

the result is this:

[http://www.facebook.com/shanibakshi.grooming.dogtraining] redirects to [http://www.facebook.com/common/browser.php]

[http://www.facebook.com/shanibakshi.grooming.dogtraining] redirects to [http://www.facebook.com/common/browser.php]

and this url  -> http://www.facebook.com/common/browser.php  is a facebook page that says my browser is old...probably because of some function in the code.....

anyway all i want to do is to check if the url in my database stays in their place with any redirection.

thanks :)

ronen.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that you want to detect redirection, but the problem is you are always getting redirected to browser.php so you get nothing but "false positives"?  In that case you probably just need to set the USERAGENT option, something like:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; rv:9.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/9.0.1');
```